# Two factor authentication invalid Code always

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

i have set up the 2fa but always it says invalid code.

i have tried it with the .net core 2.1 and 2.2. but always it says invalid code from the google as well as Microsoft authenticator.

//Enable Authenticator.cshtml

```
<p>Scan the QR Code or enter this key <kbd>@Model.SharedKey</kbd> 
into your two factor authenticator app. Spaces and casing do not matter. 
</p>
<div class="alert alert-info">To enable QR code generation please 
read our <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
Linkid=852423">documentation</a>.</div>
<div id="qrCode"></div>
<div id="qrCodeData" data- 
url="@Html.Raw(@Model.AuthenticatorUri)"></div>
//Js in Enable Authenticator.cshtml
@section Scripts {
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrCode"),
{
text: "@Html.Raw(Model.AuthenticatorUri)",
width: 200,
height: 200
});
</script>
//Enable Authenticator.cshtml.cs
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        // Strip spaces and hypens
        var verificationCode = Input.Code.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

        var is2faTokenValid = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(
            user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider, verificationCode);

        if (!is2faTokenValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Code", "Verification code is invalid.");
            await LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);
        var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        _logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' has enabled 2FA with an authenticator app.", userId);

        StatusMessage = "Your authenticator app has been verified.";

        if (await _userManager.CountRecoveryCodesAsync(user) == 0)
        {
            var recoveryCodes = await _userManager.GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync(user, 10);
            RecoveryCodes = recoveryCodes.ToArray();
            return RedirectToPage("./ShowRecoveryCodes");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./TwoFactorAuthentication");
        }
```

i want to setup the authentication but its always invalid code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same and it was caused by the time on the host, both my pc and the test environment, being off by 2 minutes from my phone.
`time.windows.com` is unavailable for time sync.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older topic, but I had the same problem.

In the end, my _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider was set incorrectly to "Email" from some old code that did 2fa over email.

So, make sure that the _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider is not changed (defaults to "Authenticator")

Maybe it will help someone!